# Run into DLL issue, works fine on other computer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an issue when i run the application, it compile fine and run fine on a computer but on another one, it got this error when running it:

```
An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in WikiDoctor.Front.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Method not found: 'System.String WikiDoctor.MySQLDAL.User.get_use_telephone()'.
```

Basically, what the code suppose to is to use EF database first edmx to get the details of the table. but cannot run on my laptop.

I have this problem for 3 days, search around but no success, the same code work fine on 2 different computers, but not on mine. it really strange, i tried to change the framework from 4.5 till 4.5.2, reinstall VS, clean up the projects, update EF to 6.1.3...still not working...

I am running out of idea.

Hope you can help

Cheers

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple assemblies (.dlls) that have the same name WikiDoctor.something.dll) and you are unintentionally using the wrong one? I recommend to search your entire disk for multiple instances of the assembly where the get_use_telephone() method is supposed to be defined.

Comment: I delete all .dll, i check the references, its pointing to write one, actually, the working laptop doesn' t has this WikiDoctor.MySQLDAL.User.get_use_telephone()'. as well

Comment: So if the working laptop doesn't have this method, and the program is still working, it means that the method was not called. Try to see why it is sometimes called sometimes not called.

Comment: i finally copied he whole project structure from the other running laptop to mine. thanks Adi

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work :-)